# mailComposeController didn't send email in swift

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I'm try to send feedback for my application. I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController`.

In my code everything is seems smooth. Probably its not about my code because after I push to send button,  inside `MFMailComposeController`  didFinishWith function  case .sent has been working without any issues.

Important point:
I was try to check my mail account in iPhone there may be a problem I've never encountered  that's why I'm asking you guys. What exactly I must to do with my phone or which place I have to check please describe me to that step by step clearly.

```
func postEmail(imageView: UIImageView,text: String) {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setToRecipients(["feedback@gmail.com"])
        mail.setSubject("HyperVPN Hakkında Geri Bildirim")
        mail.setMessageBody(text, isHTML: false)

        let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((imageView.image!)) as! NSData
        mail.addAttachmentData(imageData as Data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "imageName.png")
         self.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I expect to the return to see mail inside of  my inbox. But it couldn't seems. Nothing happened just printed mail was sent. But actually not.

Comment: Can you share your class with the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol implemented? It would help to identify the issue.

Comment: func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        
        switch result {
        case .cancelled:
            print("Mail cancelled")
        case .saved:
            print("Mail saved")
        case .sent:
            
            print("Mail sent")
        case .failed:
            
            
            print("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        default:
            break
        }
         controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: Does it print the "Mail sent" text when you send it?

Comment: yeah But I couldn't see any mail in my mailbox